# Download file with file properties from SharePoint using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

I have a requirement to download/copy files(images,videos,pdf etc) from SharePoint library along with its properties(metadata like custom properties etc.).

Thus far I have been able to use office365 library in python to copy my data from SharePoint but I don't have any idea if that will work for file metadata as well.

Any suggestions?